# Can Phonegap query the wifi system and return network names?

Tags: wifi, cordova

I checked the Phonegap API but what I would like to achieve, getting a list of available wifi networks, seems not supported.

Anyone knows if it's possible at all in the current state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get a list of available wifi networks at the moment.

PhoneGap will support reading the currently connected network SSID via the system information api (http://www.w3.org/TR/system-info-api/#network).

If you wanted to list all the wifi networks today, you would have to write a PhoneGap plugin -- assuming those APIs are actually available on the devices in which you are interested.

Comment: Regarding the W3C system info API: "Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation."

Answer (score 0):

I recently did some research on this and found out it's still not supported.

It might be useful to have a look at the [PhoneGap roadmap](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/28291160/roadmap-planning) from time to time.

Comment: Further research at the time of posting shows that on iOS those are all private APIs, so I doubt they will ever implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PhoneGap plugin for wifi info https://github.com/HondaDai/PhoneGap-WifiInfoPlugin The code is in Java which means it's for Android. However,

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

This only gives you result for the currently connected wifi network. To get a list of all wifi networks, I believe you can change the WifiInfoPlugin class and use wifiManager.getScanResults(), then store the results in an array or similar.