# How to connect to a wifi network if SSID is known using phonegap & HTML5?

Tags: android, html, cordova, wifi

I want to connect my application to a known wifi network/ssid whenever I open my application. Even if the phone is currently connected through 3G or any other wifi network.

Will this be possible using only phonegap/html5?

Comment: This is possible using Phonegap:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Comment: That is not correct, that only shows the status of the connection, it wont let you reconnect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824841/can-phonegap-query-the-wifi-system-and-return-network-names) question for reference. If you go trough the phonegap documentation there isn't anything that lets you do that out of the box.

You need to build a custom plugin that will let you do that. You need to use the native [Wifi Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)  class, and if you just Google it there are loads of guides on how to create a phonegap plugin!